# Testing Strongloop RESTapi with test database

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am developing a web application with Strongloop that will be running on Bluemix (cloud platform service).

My problem is that when i am testing i would like the tests to run against another database, not a memory database.

I have two questions regarding how to do this:

1. Were/how do i configure that a specific database is supposed to be used when running the tests? I want to be able to run the test when i deploy on Bluemix as a part of the deployment. So if i am not wrong it is not enough if i can manually with some parameter set what database would run when i am doing a "node ."?
2. Also in my server.js i am doing this to sync my database against my datamodel:

   ```
   var appModels = ['User'];
   var ds = app.dataSources.eventSeedElephantSQLDb;
   ds.isActual(appModels, function(err, actual) {
   if (!actual) {
   ds.autoupdate(appModels, function(err) {
   if (err) throw (err);
   });
   }
   });
   ```

When i am running the test i would like to run something similar but instead i would like to migrate.

In the test i am using mocha, chai and chaiHttp.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a 'Environment-specific configuration' for the tests.
Look: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration

For example you create another datasources.json configuration file, but with the name **datasources.test.json**

```
{
  "my-test-database": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "my-test-database",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

and in the test first line, you define the enviroment

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

//here I clean and create the data that I need, but you can use your database data
beforeEach(function(done) {
  app.models['City'].destroyAll();
  app.models['City'].create({name: 'city test', country: 'Brazil'});
 });

describe('/city', function() {    
  it('should find a city', function(done) {
    request(app).get('/api/city').expect(200);
  });
});
```